# Create SUMPRODUCT formula into dax format in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a formula in excel : =SUMPRODUCT(E2:E6, D2:D6)/SUM(E2:E6) which gives 3.66,
I want to create the same formula in DAX.

my data -

|  | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | cost | number |
| **2** | 1 | 1 |
| **3** | 2 | 2 |
| **4** | 3 | 3 |
| **5** | 4 | 4 |
| **6** | 5 | 5 |

Please help me to get my O/P in dax, thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `SUMX` to iterate over your table to multiply row-level values and sum them. In the below measure the dividend is your `SUMPRODUCT` equivalent.

```
Measure :=
DIVIDE ( 
    SUMX ( 
        'Table',
        'Table'[cost] * 'Table'[number]
    ),
    SUM ( 'Table'[number] )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked...btw!!! when im showing the value in a card visualisation, then i cannot increase the decimal places, it shows 34 only, any idea??

Comment: Select your measure in the Fields list, then go to `Measure tools` and select your desired format under formatting in the ribbon.

Comment: okay, i got it...(actually i did the same by selecting the chart and then edit option -> data labels -> decimal places), i did whatever you suggested but it can only change upto one decimal, i need at least two decimal places, but it is only showing one decimal places